# wordpress pagination wont render on custom page template even though its right under the loop like the documentation says so

Tags: wp-query, pagination

In Wordpress how do you get pagination to render on a custom page template?

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/pagination/

```
Examples #Examples
Loop with Pagination #Loop with Pagination
This simplified example shows where you can add pagination functions for the main loop. Add the functions just before or after the loop.

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
 
    <!-- Add the pagination functions here. -->
 
    <!-- Start of the main loop. -->
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
 
    <!-- the rest of your theme's main loop -->
 
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <!-- End of the main loop -->
 
    <!-- Add the pagination functions here. -->
 
 
<div class="nav-previous alignleft"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts' ); ?></div>
 
 
 
<div class="nav-next alignright"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts' ); ?></div>
 
 
<?php else : ?>
 
<?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?>
 
<?php endif; ?>
Expand full source code
```

So here is my code block:

```
// this variable referenced represents 16
<?php $posts_to_display = 16; ?>

<section class="flo-section resources-blocks">
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x align-center" id="container">
            <?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => $resourcesPostTypes,
                'post_status' => array('publish'),
                'orderby' => 'date',
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'post__not_in'   => array(15552, 15554, 15555),
                'posts_per_page' => $posts_to_display
            );

            $query = new WP_Query($args);
            $resourceCount = 0;

            if ($query->have_posts()) {
                while ($query->have_posts()) {
                    $query->the_post();
                    $resourceCount++;

                    $post_type = get_post_type();
                    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object($post_type);
                    if ($post_type_object) {
                        $post_type_display = esc_html($post_type_object->labels->singular_name);
                    }
                    ?>
                    <div class="cell small-12 medium-4 large-3">
                        <?php
                        $is_downloadable = get_field('is_downloadable');
                        $asset_redirect = get_field('asset_redirect');
                        if ($is_downloadable) {
                            $download_link = get_field('download_link');
                            $resource_url = $download_link['url'];
                        } else if ($asset_redirect) {
                            $resource_url = $asset_redirect;
                        } 
                        else {
                            $resource_url = get_permalink();
                        }
                        ?>
                        <a class="asset-block <?php echo ($post_type); ?>" href="<?php echo $resource_url; ?>">
                            <i class="icon-<?php echo $post_type; ?>"></i>
                            <p class="content-type"><?php echo ucfirst($post_type_display); ?></p>
                            <h4><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_title(), 20); ?></h4>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
            } else {
                // no posts found
            }

            wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>
        </div>
        <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => $resourcesPostTypes,
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post__not_in'   => array(15552, 15554, 15555)
        );

        $query = new WP_Query($args);
        if (!empty($query) && $query->post_count > $posts_to_display) {
            $display_load_more = "display:block;";
        } else {
            $display_load_more = "display:none;";
        }
        ?>
        <div style="color: red;"><?php echo $display_load_more; ?></div>
        <div class="text-center" id="load-more" style="<?php echo $display_load_more; ?>">
            // HERE IS THE PAGINATION
            <?php the_posts_pagination(); ?>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="next_page" id="next_page" value="2" />
        <div class="hide" id="resources-loader">
            <img src="<?= get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/ajax-loader.gif" />
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I thought maybe it wasnt close enough to the loop like the documentation said so I brought it closer

```
<section class="flo-section resources-blocks">
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x align-center" id="container">
            <?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => $resourcesPostTypes,
                'post_status' => array('publish'),
                'orderby' => 'date',
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'post__not_in'   => array(15552, 15554, 15555),
                'posts_per_page' => $posts_to_display
            );

            $query = new WP_Query($args);
            $resourceCount = 0;

            if ($query->have_posts()) {
                while ($query->have_posts()) {
                    $query->the_post();
                    $resourceCount++;

                    $post_type = get_post_type();
                    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object($post_type);
                    if ($post_type_object) {
                        $post_type_display = esc_html($post_type_object->labels->singular_name);
                    }
                    ?>
                    <div class="cell small-12 medium-4 large-3">
                        <?php
                        $is_downloadable = get_field('is_downloadable');
                        $asset_redirect = get_field('asset_redirect');
                        if ($is_downloadable) {
                            $download_link = get_field('download_link');
                            $resource_url = $download_link['url'];
                        } else if ($asset_redirect) {
                            $resource_url = $asset_redirect;
                        } 
                        else {
                            $resource_url = get_permalink();
                        }
                        ?>
                        <a class="asset-block <?php echo ($post_type); ?>" href="<?php echo $resource_url; ?>">
                            <i class="icon-<?php echo $post_type; ?>"></i>
                            <p class="content-type"><?php echo ucfirst($post_type_display); ?></p>
                            <h4><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_title(), 20); ?></h4>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
                // HELLOOOOO PAGINATION WHERE ARE YOU????
                the_posts_pagination();
            } else {
                // no posts found
            }

            wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>
        </div>
        <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => $resourcesPostTypes,
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post__not_in'   => array(15552, 15554, 15555)
        );

        $query = new WP_Query($args);
        if (!empty($query) && $query->post_count > $posts_to_display) {
            $display_load_more = "display:block;";
        } else {
            $display_load_more = "display:none;";
        }
        ?>
        <div style="color: red;"><?php echo $display_load_more; ?></div>
        <div class="text-center" id="load-more" style="<?php echo $display_load_more; ?>">
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="next_page" id="next_page" value="2" />
        <div class="hide" id="resources-loader">
            <img src="<?= get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/ajax-loader.gif" />
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And then I realized:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30066849/why-the-posts-pagination-function-not-working

> the_posts_pagination only works in post listings pages like index.php
> or archive.php. It will not work in a custom template, for example.
>
> See here :
> https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_posts_pagination

Okay, so let's try `posts_nav_link()`

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/posts_nav_link/

> Displays the post pages link navigation for previous and next pages.

```
<section class="flo-section resources-blocks">
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x align-center" id="container">
            <?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => $resourcesPostTypes,
                'post_status' => array('publish'),
                'orderby' => 'date',
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'post__not_in'   => array(15552, 15554, 15555),
                'posts_per_page' => $posts_to_display
            );

            $query = new WP_Query($args);
            $resourceCount = 0;

            if ($query->have_posts()) {
                while ($query->have_posts()) {
                    $query->the_post();
                    $resourceCount++;

                    $post_type = get_post_type();
                    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object($post_type);
                    if ($post_type_object) {
                        $post_type_display = esc_html($post_type_object->labels->singular_name);
                    }
                    ?>
                    <div class="cell small-12 medium-4 large-3">
                        <?php
                        $is_downloadable = get_field('is_downloadable');
                        $asset_redirect = get_field('asset_redirect');
                        if ($is_downloadable) {
                            $download_link = get_field('download_link');
                            $resource_url = $download_link['url'];
                        } else if ($asset_redirect) {
                            $resource_url = $asset_redirect;
                        } 
                        else {
                            $resource_url = get_permalink();
                        }
                        ?>
                        <a class="asset-block <?php echo ($post_type); ?>" href="<?php echo $resource_url; ?>">
                            <i class="icon-<?php echo $post_type; ?>"></i>
                            <p class="content-type"><?php echo ucfirst($post_type_display); ?></p>
                            <h4><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_title(), 20); ?></h4>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
            } else {
                // no posts found
            }

            wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>
        </div>
        <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => $resourcesPostTypes,
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post__not_in'   => array(15552, 15554, 15555)
        );

        $query = new WP_Query($args);
        if (!empty($query) && $query->post_count > $posts_to_display) {
            $display_load_more = "display:block;";
        } else {
            $display_load_more = "display:none;";
        }
        ?>
        <div style="color: red;"><?php echo $display_load_more; ?></div>
        <div class="text-center" id="load-more" style="<?php echo $display_load_more; ?>">
            <?php posts_nav_link(); ?>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="next_page" id="next_page" value="2" />
        <div class="hide" id="resources-loader">
            <img src="<?= get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/ajax-loader.gif" />
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Still nothing....

[image]

How do you get Wordpress to render pagination on a custom page?

MORE EDITS:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42480019/showing-prev-next-post-links-doesnt-work

> In Layman language it is a wordpress function to fetch
> posts/custom-posts. Internally it calls WP_Query function. Or you can
> use WP_Query instead of this. 'posts_nav_link' function does not work
> with WP_Query & get_posts function. You can try this to get next
> previous links.

Got it, ok, how do we paginate with WP_Query? Let's see

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/

Looking promising, can we work it with WP_Query() ?

[Pagination when using wp_query?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/254199/pagination-when-using-wp-query)

> WordPress comes with a handy function called paginate_links() which
> does the heavy lifting. In the example above, the custom WP_Query
> object $query is used instead of the global $wp_query object.

Looking good ok lets try it:

```
<section class="flo-section resources-blocks">
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x align-center" id="container">
            <?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => $resourcesPostTypes,
                'post_status' => array('publish'),
                'orderby' => 'date',
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'post__not_in'   => array(15552, 15554, 15555),
                'posts_per_page' => $posts_to_display
            );

            $query = new WP_Query($args);
            $resourceCount = 0;

            if ($query->have_posts()) {
                while ($query->have_posts()) {
                    $query->the_post();
                    $resourceCount++;

                    $post_type = get_post_type();
                    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object($post_type);
                    if ($post_type_object) {
                        $post_type_display = esc_html($post_type_object->labels->singular_name);
                    }
                    ?>
                    <div class="cell small-12 medium-4 large-3">
                        <?php
                        $is_downloadable = get_field('is_downloadable');
                        $asset_redirect = get_field('asset_redirect');
                        if ($is_downloadable) {
                            $download_link = get_field('download_link');
                            $resource_url = $download_link['url'];
                        } else if ($asset_redirect) {
                            $resource_url = $asset_redirect;
                        } 
                        else {
                            $resource_url = get_permalink();
                        }
                        ?>
                        <a class="asset-block <?php echo ($post_type); ?>" href="<?php echo $resource_url; ?>">
                            <i class="icon-<?php echo $post_type; ?>"></i>
                            <p class="content-type"><?php echo ucfirst($post_type_display); ?></p>
                            <h4><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_title(), 20); ?></h4>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
                paginate_links();
            } else {
                // no posts found
            }

            wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>
        </div>
        <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => $resourcesPostTypes,
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post__not_in'   => array(15552, 15554, 15555)
        );

        $query = new WP_Query($args);
        if (!empty($query) && $query->post_count > $posts_to_display) {
            $display_load_more = "display:block;";
        } else {
            $display_load_more = "display:none;";
        }
        ?>
        <div style="color: red;"><?php echo $display_load_more; ?></div>
        <div class="text-center" id="load-more" style="<?php echo $display_load_more; ?>">
            <?php paginate_links(); ?>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="next_page" id="next_page" value="2" />
        <div class="hide" id="resources-loader">
            <img src="<?= get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/ajax-loader.gif" />
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Still nothing.

Comment: My understanding is that none of your code examples that contain the problem have a standard loop, you've instead used a custom loop and ignored the main query. The pagination functions all work with the pagination of the main loop, not your custom secondary loops built with `new WP_Query`. If you want to modify the content pulled in to the post query/loop, you should have used `pre_get_posts` instead of discarding it and creating a brand new additional query.  Also one of your examples has unlimited posts per page ( `-1` ) so it could never have a second page.

Comment: Also your code blocks formatting is broken, can you edit your question to fix the code blocks so that the code is code and the non-code is not code? Use 3 backticks to do this rather than indentation as it's easier

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/84429/use-wp-query-with-have-posts Hmmmm. i dont understand, isn't `$query->have_posts()` a main loop? can you explain hiw mine is custom?

Comment: no, there is only one main loop, accessed via `the_post`/`have_posts()`. What you have is a custom loop from a custom query object. Why would the pagination functions know about your `$query` variable? Computers are extremely literal, functions won't infer that you meant it to use that one not the other one, and your `new WP_Query` does not replace the main query, it's still there being unused. WP still went and fetched all the posts for the main query, the template just ignores them and makes an extra query.

Comment: the main query is the primary query that WP creates aka the `global $wp_query` the quote refers to, the one that loaded your page based on data from the URL, that allowed your page template to be shown in the first place. Even if you plug your custom query object into the pagination functions by overriding the total and current page, you'll still get a 404 if you access page 5 but the main query only has 4 pages, and you've still doubled the number of queries on your page.

Comment: What you're trying to do here is essentially reinvent the custom post type archive and template using a page template. This is commonly done either so that a page builder can be used too customize it with a custom query thrown in to get around that problem, or, by people who want a custom URL but don't know that it can be done using parameters in `register_post_type` so they create a page and use a page template

Comment: thankfully if you wanted to continue down this path there are literally hundreds of other questions on the stack asking why pagination doesn't work with their custom query. You'll also notice that your examples have a second custom query at the end for the load more button which doesn't make much sense. All the information to figure out if an AJAX load more button is necessary is already in the `$query` object ( how do you think `paginate_links` knows how many pages to display )

Comment: Also, be very wary of setting `posts_per_page` to `-1`, and of using `post__not_in`. The parameters ending in `__not_in` or that use `NOT` comparators are ultra expensive and involve fully in memory table copies on the database, they're extremely slow. Much faster to ask for what you want, never what you don't want. Or to check for and skip those posts in PHP

Comment: @TomJNowell "thankfully if you wanted to continue down this path there are literally hundreds of other questions on the stack asking why pagination doesn't work with their custom query. " I see that but one of them are working can you link to one /

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/254199/pagination-when-using-wp-query none of these work

Comment: I think the problem is that you have taken pagination and an AJAX load more feature and combined them and neither of them work separately, but because you've mixed them up it's impossible to integrate any of the solutions you've found, and they don't make sense. Delete your AJAX loading code with the load more, and add normal fixed pagination _then_ look at adding AJAX load more code afterwards. That entire second loop should just be deleted and destroyed, it's confusing and overwrites important things, and creates a huge mess